# Bulk change in database through the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a User model, where a user can be `Gold` or not (it's a boolean).
I would like to update specific users (more than 500) from `Gold: false` to `Gold: true` thanks to their user_id

How can I do it through the rails console ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `#update_all`. If you have the ids:

```
User.where(id: ids).update_all(gold: true)
```

It's fast as it sends a single SQL command to db and doesn't invoke validation or callbacks.